# Javascript for command line utilities

Tags: javascript, command-line

Given a need to write command line utilities to do common tasks like uploading files to a remote FTP site, downloading data from a remote MySQL database  etc.

Is it practical to use JavaScript for this sort of thing? I know there are JavaScript interpreters that can be run from the command line, but are there libraries for things like FTP and database access the way there are for e.g. Java?  If so, what's the best place to look for them? (Google searches with JavaScript in the keywords always seem to return many pages of browser specific things.)

And is there a way to package a JavaScript program up as a standalone executable on Windows?

Update: I've decided Python is a better tool for this kind of job, but the answers to the original question are still good ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/#download) is by far the best environment for running non-browser JS.  I've used Rhino and SpiderMonkey, and there's a pretty huge difference in everything from the basics like how errors are handled to the size of the community using the tool. Node is pitched for "server-side" JS - building server apps in JS.  It's great for this.  But it works equally well for building command line tools.

The NPM package manager (bundled with Node) provides a nice global directory for finding and installing packages.  It works much better than other language equivalents like PECL / Pear / CPAN / etc.  Several high quality tools like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), The [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) templating language, and the [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) compiler are all already available through NPM/Node:

```
npm install -g jshint, coffee-script, jade
jshint my_code.js
jade < my.jade > my.html
```

For args parsing, there are packages like [commander.js](http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/9103188408/commander-js-nodejs-command-line-interfaces-made-easy).  I currently use a heavily extended version of Commander in my [underscore-cli](http://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) command-line tool.

For messing with JSON or for doing command-line JS work (similar to "perl -pe"), check out [underscore-cli](http://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) - It's a really powerful tool for processing JSON data, processing underscore templates, and running JS expressions from the command-line.  I use it for 1001 different things that would otherwise be really annoying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you say npm is better than cpan?

Comment: Specific to CPAN, one gripe is that it wants me to walk through a 15 step "setup" prior to use ... just silly.  From a usability / CLI perspective, npm is more pleasant. As for more substantial philosophical deltas...  npm handles recursive dependencies quite differently.  With PERL (and ruby and most other scripting languages), you have a global module path and it gets tricky to use modules A and B if they each require a different version of module C.  npm handles this well, though it downloads full transitive dependency closure each time you install a module (also silly).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the background.  I've only used python pip extensively, npm once or twice.  cpan was always well regarded by the slashdot crowd however.

Comment: How does npm "work much better than CPAN"? npmjs.org is a mess (try picking a CSV module - you'll get a ton of search results, out of which 80% are irrelevant or just crap) because it has no ratings or comments feature. I filed an [issue about that on GitHub](https://github.com/isaacs/npm-www/issues/298). To address your gripe about the setup steps: use [cpanm](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/App-cpanminus). No setup required.

Answer (score 8):

Standalone executable?

By the way you ask the question, I'm not sure if you are aware, but the Windows Script Host - included in Windows - allows you to run .js files from the command-line.  Your javascript will not be an executable, it will remain a script, a text file.  The script runs within cscript.exe, which is provided by WSH.  There's no compilation required.  Maybe you knew all that.

I use Javascript this way for various utilities on Windows.

I think your instinct is right on the availability of libraries. You are sort of *on your own* to find all those things.  Although, once you find them, it's not hard to package Javascript libraries as COM components and allow re-use from anywhere.  [See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848246/how-can-i-use-javascript-within-an-excel-macro) of packaging the Google Diff/Patch/Match Javascript library in COM.

**Addendum**: Once a bit of code is available within COM, it can be consumed by any Javascript running on the machine.  Some examples of COM objects available to Javascript scripts running in WSH:

- [MSXML2.XMLHTTP object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296772) - used in AJAX, but can be used for any HTTP communication. There also an object for the XSLT engine so you can do transforms from script.
- [Excel.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8(VS.85).aspx) - allows you to open up Excel spreadsheets and automate them from Javascript.
- [Communicator.UIAutomation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb758725.aspx) - automate MS Communicator (send IM's via script)
- [COM objects for Google Earth](http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=%2bgoogleearth.applicationge).
- [SlowAES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270510/how-to-encrypt-in-vbscript-using-aes/858525#858525) - an all-Javascript implementation of AES encryption.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Rhino to compile Javascript into Java byte code, and get access to all Java libraries.

Or you could use JScript.net, and get access to the .net libraries. .net includes a jsc.exe that produces exe-files.

Both of these requires the respective framework to be installed to be able to run.

Answer (score 4):

Rhino is bundled with JDK 1.6, jrunscript.exe in the bin directory will allow you to run any Javascript you want.  Since it runs under Java you get access to any Java libraries that you may have.

We use it from the command line extensively.  It's very good at that.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to write these utilities as AIR applications - They can be written in JavaScript and need not have a UI. They have access to the command line, and there are existing ActionScript 3 libraries that can handle FTP etc. These ActionScript APIs can be called from JS, in AIR applications. AIR applications also have access to a sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

[jslibs](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/) is a good standalone JavaScript runtime that support many 3rd party open source libraries like zlib, SQLite, NSPR, libiconv, libTomCrypt, OpenGL, ...