# slowAES encryption and java  decryption

Tags: java, aes, cryptography

I've tried to implement the same steps as discussed in [AES .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149611/getting-slowaes-and-rijndaelmanaged-class-in-net-to-play-together)

but with no success , i can't seem to get java and slowAes to play toghter ... attached is my code i'm sorry i can't add more this is my first time trying to deal with encryption would appreciate any help

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue = getKeyBytes("12345678901234567890123456789012");

private static final byte[] INIT_VECTOR = new byte[16];
private static IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(INIT_VECTOR);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String encoded = encrypt("watson?");
    System.out.println(encoded);
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGORITHM);
    // SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    // key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyValue));
    return key;
}

private static byte[] getKeyBytes(String key) {
    byte[] hash = DigestUtils.sha(key); // key.getBytes()
    byte[] saltedHash = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(hash, 0, saltedHash, 0, 16);
    return saltedHash;
}

public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec);
    byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
    return encryptedValue;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
    String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
    return decryptedValue;
}
```

the bytes returned are different 
thanks in advance .

Comment: SHA1 alone is not an adequate password based key derivation function. Do not use any sun.* classes.

Answer (score 2):

You encrypt data using AES in CBC mode and PKC5Padding but you decrypt using just plain AES. In your decrypt method you need to create the Cipher using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" just like you do in the encrypt method.