# Cryptography-grade random numbers in Access 2010

Tags: random, hash, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to come up with a marginally secure way of storing passwords in a networked application that uses an Access 2010 frontend. To this end, I am attempting to implement Bcrypt's algorithm in Visual Basic for Applications.

I have found that to fetch a random number in Access, one must use Randomize() and Rnd(). However, it seems that the output of these methods are predictable and should not be used for cryptography. Should I just go with it because *anything* is better than storing passwords in plaintext? Or is there a better solution? Of course, ideally someone else has already written this, but I can't find it.

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038504/aes-encrypting-a-microsoft-access-field-via-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found [this SHA-256 digest hashing algorithm](http://www.frez.co.uk/vb6.aspx) implemented in VBA which doesn't appear to use (or need!) random numbers.